# Rails and jQuery Mobile:

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a desktop version as well as a mobile version (currently not fully-functional) of a project that I'm working on.

For Desktop, I can render partials and replace DOM objects quite easily:

'controller.rb'

```
def func
    @blah = "hey"
    @button_label = "button"
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
end
```

'_func.html.erb'

```
<%= blah %>
<%= button_to @button_label, {:controller => "controller", :action => "func"}, :method => "put", :remote => true, "data-role" => 'button' %>
```

'func.js.erb'

```
$('#camera_container').html("<%=j render 'func' %>")
```

The above code doesn't function as it does on Desktop. I have a completely separate mobile section, so any code changes will not affect the desktop, **but the controllers are shared.**

Of course, there's a button initially loaded whose action points to the func function in controller.rb, but then fails to "replace itself."

The above snippets work for the desktop version using standard jQuery. With jQuery-mobile, I receive a page loading error. Now, I feel that this has something to do with the buttons not being enhanced and the fact that I'm wanting to replace one button with a different button (at the very, very least).

Comment: You can just use Jquery and not jquery-mobile on your mobile app.

Comment: I'd have to give that a shot, but would the UI stay the same? I don't necessarily need the jQuery-mobile functions, just the CSS and button layouts. I'm at work atm, but I had the idea of turning off AJAX through the 'mobileinit' to see if it that would work.

Comment: Well all depends on what you want from the framework.

Comment: With jQuery-mobile, I'd like to click a button, have rails generate a new button, replace the old button. With that new button, it will call a different function in the controller and based on what happens inside, generate a button very similar to the button that was present before being replaced. Essentially: button-a -> func -> replace button-a with button-b -> diff_func -> replaces button-b with button-a (generated in a different partial).

To be specific: the button displayed has a different function. Think of stop-and-go. One starts, one stops. If started, ask to stop. But with partials.

Comment: How jquery Mobile can help you with that? jQuery alone is enough imo

Comment: It is, but I want to try it with jQuery-mobile first, and if it doesn't work, fall back to jQuery and attempt to mimic the UI that jQuery-mobile provides me.